# Media Player - File path on Device Not Recognized

Tags: android

I have a voice note called Hello.m4a

Here is the file path to the audio on my device:

[image]

I want to set this voice note to a MediaPlayer object and can't for the life of me figure out how. Here's my latest attempt but I keep getting a null object error message:

```
    String voice = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/VoiceRecorder/Hello.m4a";
    Log.d("MAIN",voice);
    MediaPlayer mpintro = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(voice));
    mpintro.start();
```

Here's what my log message produces:

```
/storage/emulated/0/VoiceRecorder/Hello.m4a
```

Here is the logcat message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you.

I have these permissions in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the Uri add `"file://"` before the file path i.e.:

`MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("file://" + voice);`

You have to let MediaPlayer know explicitly its a file, as well as a http stream etc..

Also if you're targeting API 23+ you'll need runtime permissions for access to files on storiage.

Comment: I added it but still nothing. Here is exactly what's getting parse: file://storage/emulated/0/VoiceRecorder/Hello.m4a

Comment: should be 3 forward slashes

Comment: Sorry meant to write file:///storage/emulated/0/VoiceRecorder/Hello.m4a

Comment: Still getting the same error message.  I tried doing this and same thing.................... String voiceNotePath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + "/storage/emulated/0/VoiceRecorder/Hello.m4a";      mpintro = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("file://" + voiceNotePath)); My log statement for this is : file:///sdcard/storage/emulated/0/VoiceRecorder/Hello.m4a

Comment: Rule out the file as the nullPointer, create a new file, add `voice` as the path, check it `exists()` and `canRead()` - if it was Permissions it would throw `SecurityException`

Comment: What do you mean by "add voice as the path"? What would the syntax for the look like? I appreciate the help

Comment: `File file = new File(voice);`  `Log.d("Main", " voice exists : " + file.exists() + ", can read : " + file.canRead());`  - your looking for true to both.

Comment: Damn. It's False on both. Idk because the file clearly exists. The exact path is in that image above. I just can't figure out how to get to it.

Comment: If you're targeting APi 23 and up you'll need to include runtime permissions - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: That's it! Wow. It's never simple. Please update your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Personally I think that runtime permissions model is flawed driven by user paranoia - permissions can be revoked at anytime by a user in settings, and its left to the developer to handle and always check.. since when did desktop applications ever ask for permissions to write/read files ...